# Python 3: Searching A Text File Smartly

Tags: python, search, text, python-3.x

I have a large text file (`data`) which has the following layout: `a|b|c|d|e|f` (although `b` can have pipes within it). I search the text file with the following code:

```
results = 0
Data_List = []
searchphrase = input("Search: ")
with open('data', 'r', encoding="utf8") as inF:
    for line in inF:
        if searchphrase in line:
            a, *b, c, d, e, f = line.strip().split('|')
            b = '|'.join(b)
            results += 1
            print("\n\n", results, "\n", "A: " + a + "\n", "B: " + b + "\n", "C: " + c + "\n", "D: " + d + "\n", "E: " + e + "\n", "F: " + f + "\n\n")
            Data_List.append(f)
```

`b` is a piece of text that contains the title which is what the user is really searching for in the code above (for example: `The Lion King`). However, the search is very specific and only returns exact results (in other words, if I searched `The Lion King` then `the lion king` would not be returned). How can I make the search be less specific and more generalised (think Google searches)?

Comment: Use regular expressions. As far as case is concerned, utilize the regex flag `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: You mean a fuzzy search?

Comment: Fuzzy searching is probably more like what I mean. Regex still seems too specific as I am dealing with both data that is user generated and a search term which is generated by a different user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at [Whoosh](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/).

> Whoosh is a library of classes and functions for indexing text and then searching the index. It allows you to develop custom search engines for your content. For example, if you were creating blogging software, you could use Whoosh to add a search function to allow users to search blog entries.

It can handle:

- [Stemming, variations, and accent folding](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/stemming.html#stemming-variations-and-accent-folding)
- [Suggest replacements for mis-typed words](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/spelling.html#did-you-mean-correcting-errors-in-user-queries)
- [N-gram indexing (search as you type)](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/ngrams.html)

An much more... Whoosh is pure-Python and Python 3 compatible.

Unfortunately fuzzy search is linked to [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), one of the most complex subjects in [CS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science), so it is not as easy as using some magic regular expression trick.

NLP is hard, period. That is why Google uses a [Pigeon Cluster](http://www.google.com/onceuponatime/technology/pigeonrank.html) to rank results instead of computer algorithms (LoL).